# NPM search remote packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package-managers

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to search remote NPM packages in my installation of version 0.2.19. `npm ls` and `npm search` (one an apparent alias of the other) display only locally installed packages. The associated help dialog/manpage lacks an obvious answer, except this ambiguous reference to a configuration option:

> CONFIGURATION
>
> listopts
>          Default: ""
>
> ```
>    A whitespace-separated list of extra args that are always passed to npm ls
>
>    For example: listopts = remote
>
>    npm ls
>
>    The output here will always filter by remote
> ```

Should I conclude that the only way for npm to search remote repositories is to add a setting in a configuration file, or *is there a command that I can use?*

Comment: `$ npm --version` should response 1.1.0, if your really running 0.2.19 then update

Comment: Looks like [the package I installed from the Ubuntu extra repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=npm) is hopelessly outdated. I suppose I'll have to do a dirty, package-less install.

Comment: Always install node from the source, npm is bundled with node

Comment: @Raynos Why should I always install node from the source?

Comment: Because that's how it works, you want the latest version from the source, or you use a node version manager (`n`) that installs from the source for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
raynos@raynos-MS-7681:~$ npm search ncore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1330640201000
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1330640201000
NAME   DESCRIPTION                        AUTHOR   DATE              KEYWORDS
ncore  Core library for your application  =raynos  2012-02-28 11:49  core archit
raynos@raynos-MS-7681:~$ npm --version
1.1.0
```